# How to add HDFS data using spark

Tags: bash, scala, hadoop, apache-spark

I am new to spark and want add hdfs data using spark.
Say I am doing something like this in bash but takes time if data is huge,therefore want to use the same using spark.
eg:

```
    year=2016

for((month=1;month<10;month++)) 
do 
    tot1=$(hadoop fs -du -s /inputdata1/year=$year/month=0$month | awk '{SUM += $1} END {print SUM/(1024*1024*1024*1024)}') 

    tot2=$(hadoop fs -du -s /inputdata2/year=$year/month=0$month | awk '{SUM += $1} END {print SUM/(1024*1024*1024*1024)}') 

    tot3=$(hadoop fs -du -s /inputdata3/year=$year/month=0$month | awk '{SUM += $1} END {print SUM/(1024*1024*1024*1024)}') 

    tot4=$(hadoop fs -du -s /inputdata4/year=$year/month=0$month | awk '{SUM += $1} END {print SUM/(1024*1024*1024*1024)}') 

    tot=$(echo $tot1+$tot2+$tot3+$tot4|bc)

        printf 'Total Data in month %d\t%.2f \n' "$month" "$tot"

done
```

Comment: Some additional clarity would be useful.  Is your question just about loading data files in bulk from HDFS into Spark? Or is your question about how to perform a particular analysis on the data? Or both...

Answer (score 0):

> Please don't mark this answer as not useful, I joined yesterday and I am not able to add comments.

can you please be more clear about what are you trying to achieve?

You wish to read data in spark and then do what?
What kind of data do you have?

If you desired output like below ?

```
Month         Count
2017-03       123
2017-02       234
2017-01       345
2016-12       456
```

Try if the below code works out for you or not.

```
 import sqlContext.implicits._
 sqlContext.read.text("/inputdata1/").toDF().groupBy("Month","Year").sum("*")
```

Comment: Want to read the data and generate graphs monthwise in zeppelin.

Comment: This will provide data ingress monthwise report.Above is working fine but failing after two months and taking too long.Perhaps with spark it will be simple at the same time less time consuming.

Comment: If your desired output look like what mentioned in the answer?

Comment: Yes,that should be fine.

Comment: Try if the code mentioned in the ans works out for you or not.

Answer (score 0):

Start by checking out the Spark API docs for [SparkContext](http://spark.apache.org/docs/latest/api/scala/index.html#org.apache.spark.SparkContext).

If all you want to do is count the number of files in a directory, then I think this should work...

```
val conf = new SparkConf().setAppName("MyFirstSparkJob")
val sc = new SparkContext(conf)
val count1 = sc.wholeTextFiles("hdfs://inputdata1/*").count
```

...note that  `sc.wholeTextFiles` returns a `RDD[String, String]` where each pair has the form (file-name, file-contents). From here there are lots of things that one could do to actually analyze the data in `file-contents`.

Comment: Not number of files but the size of the files,which du command does on bash.

Comment: @shaheer01 You could use something like [SizeEstimator](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/util/SizeEstimator.html) as discussed in this [SO](https://spark.apache.org/docs/1.4.0/api/java/org/apache/spark/util/SizeEstimator.html) post.